# Add values together in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm making an EPOS system at the minute. I have a DataGridView set up for all scanned items. What I am in need of it doing is, everything under the "price" column, I need it to add together and then change the label `totalLbl.Text` to the total.

I've had a look on Google but unable to come up with a decent enough search term to find anything useful. I've tried:

```
String str;

str = DG.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString();
```

However, that just throws an index error.

The DataGridView name is `DG` (the only one on the Form)

Column names: `Item`, `Quantity`, `Price` (`Price` is the one I'm trying to get working!)

Total label: `totalLbl.Text`

Any suggestions would be great! Thanks.

Comment: You don't seem to be selecting any cells.  Is there any chance you can make your data source do the math for you?  Kind of a Select price, qty, price*qty as total from yourdata

Comment: I've just been able too do the math which does price*qty, only problem I've having now is adding everything under the price column together into one and then updating a label with that total? Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: What type of data source does the datagrid have? If you have a DataTable you can use: totalLbl.Text = dataTable.Compute("SUM(Price)", string.Empty).ToString(). In case you're using a List you can use Linq like this totalLbl.Text = itemsList.Sum(i => i.Price).ToString()

Comment: I've been able to get this too work finally, instead of just trying to read all of the cells and calculate that way, I'm taking the price before it enters the table, store it to a temp variable, and then do the calculations that way. I know it's probably not the best idea but it works and that's all I care about right now. It's been a long day! Thanks for the advice and help though!

Answer (score 0):

Try checking Selected Rows instead of Selected Cells.